# Communication between C++ and C# in a metro app

Tags: c#, c++, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm building a metro application where I need to call call a C# lib from C++. Simply calling the C# code wasn't hard. The problem is how I should communicate back from C# to C++. How do I do this in winRT? Is it possible? Because all the examples I've found only have a one way communication.

Comment: You have to compile against the WinRT profile with both the C# code and the C++ code.  If you can communicate with C# within C++ the reverse is just as easy.

Comment: I suppose you mean communicate between two winrt components, one built with C# and one with C++? and what exactly do you plan to "communicate"?

Comment: I would like to be able to call callbacks implemented in the C++ code from the C# code. From what I understand, I can't simply include a c++ header in the C# code which would allow me to call the callback.

Comment: Ok, it actually was really simple. I could implement a C# interface in my C++ code which I could use as a callback from the C# lib.

Comment: @user499986 then you should post that as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: @Naszta:  C++/CLI cannot be used to target WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it actually was really simple. I could implement a C# interface in my C++ code which I could use as a callback from the C# lib.